# C function to read 2 values from file

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

I have a .txt file with some numbers in it (e.g. 1 2 3 etc), and I want to read the first two numbers from this file, assign first number to val1, second number to val2, but I have to do this using a separate function. I thought that the best way to do this would be to declare an array of two integers, and then assign those scanned numbers to these integers in array. Here's my main:

```
int main()
{
    int val1, val2;
    int array[2];
    char file_name[10];

    printf("Filename: ");
    scanf("%s",&file_name);

    getValues(file_name, array);
    val1 = array[0];
    val2 = array[1];
}
```

The function that reads 2 number from file and saves them to array looks like this:

```
void getValues(char *file_name, int *array)
{
    FILE *f;
    if((f = fopen(file_name, "r") == NULL))
        {
            fputs(stderr, "Cannot open this file!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    fscanf(f,"%d %d",&array[0],&array[1]);
    printf("1st value: %d\n 2nd value: %d",array[0],array[1]);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Program compiles, but returns some rubbish value for integers in array, and eventually crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use the address-of operand `&` on arrays, it doesn't really do what you expect it to. It does work *in this case*, but just doesn't to what you think it does.

Comment: As for your problem, is the size of `size_t` the same as the size of `int` (check using e.g. the `sizeof` operator)? Have you made a forward-declaration of the `getValues` function before you called it? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and also please show us the contents of the file? Also, in the future please enable more warnings from the compiler, it might tell you something useful.

Comment: Maybe you meant this `if((f = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL)` ?

Comment: @Programmer400 Isn't that what the OP already written?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm not 100 % sure, I'm testing the code so that I also learn. My syntax highlight reported the original code as "pointer from integer"

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "Taking pointer from integer without a cast". I tested and modified the code and put in an answer, but I don't know why `size_t` was there. The code printed the numbers from the file when I tested.

Answer (score 0):

I start with fixing the warning:

```
$ gcc main.c 
main.c: In function ‘getValues’:
main.c:7:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     if((f = fopen(file_name, "r") == NULL))
```

Then it worked for me with just some slight type changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getValues(char *file_name, int *array)
{
    FILE *f;
    if( (f = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Cannot open this file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(f,"%d %d",&array[0],&array[1]);
    printf("1st value: %d\n 2nd value: %d",array[0],array[1]);
    fclose(f);
}

int main()
{
    int val1, val2;
    int array[2];
    char file_name[10];

    printf("Filename: ");
    scanf("%s",file_name);

    getValues(file_name, array);
    val1 = array[0];
    val2 = array[1];
}
```

File data.txt

```
2 3
```

Output

```
/system/cmake/generated/gnu-fadf49ce/fadf49ce/Debug/gnu
Filename: data.txt
1st value: 2
 2nd value: 3
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yup, it works. Looks like I did something wrong with 'if'.

Comment: @pitolek You can compare the statements `if( (f = fopen(file_name, "r")) == NULL )` `if((f = fopen(file_name, "r") == NULL))` where the last statement results in a warning. We can go through the warnings your original code had to learn from our mistakes. Why did you use `size_t` ? It is not compatible with integers if I try to analyze and compile it.

Comment: Validate, validate, what if the first character in the file is `z`? Always, always validate the `scanf` *family* function returns. Why use `void` as type (other than that is what the OP did in question), pick a return that allows indication of success failure.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes we need error-checking. My code was just meant to make the correct output and not crash for that single case of digits in the file. I need to learn error-handling in C with `perror` assertions and return values for nicer coder that we can validate, validate and even over-validate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write two functions for it in the first place.
But even if it is then this should work just fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void reader(int,char *);
int main()
{
 int fd;
 char buf[3];
 if((fd=open("text.txt",O_RDONLY))==-1)
   {
    perror("can't open file or file does not exist\n");
    exit(0);
   }
 printf("The values are:\n");
 reader(fd,buf);
 return 0;
}

void reader(int fd,char buf[])
{
 read(fd,buf,3);
 printf("value of first integer val1 is: %c\n",buf[0]);
 printf("value of seconnd integer val2 is: %c\n",buf[1]);
 close(fd);
}
```